# Settings in Ubuntu 17.10 don't work

Tags: gnome, 17.10

I updated 17.04 to 17.10 and some settings just plain don't work. One of my problems are settings for touchpad — I want to inverse the scroll method and I want the touchpad to be disabled while I'm typing. Another problem is login screen on startup — I don't want it, and it's there. No matter what I do regarding those settings in either `gnome-control-center` or `dconf-editor`, nothing changes — I'm still stuck with inverted scrolling, login screen on startup and touchpad not being disabled while I'm typing.

Answer (score 0):

I can partially answer some of your questions.

To try and enable "Natural Scrolling" on the touchpad, open the Settings control panel and look to see if this setting is available for your touchpad...

[image]

To disable the login screen, open the `Settings -> Details -> Users', and change the following item...

[image]

To disable the touchpad when typing, I like `Touchpad Indicator` GNOME Shell extension.

Find it at https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/131/touchpad-indicator/

Comment: That's my problem though, these settings in GNOME's default Settings app just don't do anything. No matter which way I set this "Natural Scrolling" switch, the touchpad scrolling is always the same way, and it's not the way I'm used to. As for "Users and Groups", I can't find this exact window, the app search doesn't yield anything with this name. Is this the same as `Settings -> Details -> Users`? There is a switch called `Automatic Login`, but it, once again, doesn't seem to influence anything.

Comment: @Alex my mistake, you're correct, it's `Settings -> Details -> Users`, and I've updated my answer. As to your problem, create a new user account, and see if the settings work there. If they do, then the problem is with your user account/directory.